LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer returns null but wms layer is loaded
I want to add a WMS layer to ArcGIS Pro and modify some parameters of the layer. But with the following code the returned featLayer object is null.
In ArcGIS Pro the WMS layer is loaded correctly even with the parameters like name and visibility. So where can be the problem?
CIMWMSLayer wmsMapLayer = null;

LayerCreationParams lyrParams = null;
var serverConnection = new CIMInternetServerConnection { URL = "https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_topplus_open?request=GetCapabilities"/*src.MapUrl*/, Anonymous=true, HideUserProperty=true };
var connection = new CIMWMSServiceConnection { ServerConnection = serverConnection , Version= "1.3.0"/*src.Version*/, LayerName=src.Title};

// Add a new layer to the map
var layerParams = new LayerCreationParams(connection)
{
    Name="Hello World",
    IsVisible = false
};
FeatureLayer featLayer = null;
await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
{
    featLayer = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer<ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping.FeatureLayer>(layerParams, MapView.Active.Map);
    // featLayer here is null but in application it is loaded correctly
});

if (featLayer != null)
{
    CIMBaseLayer bsl = featLayer.GetDefinition();
    if (bsl is CIMWMSLayer) wmsMapLayer = bsl as CIMWMSLayer;
}


Is there a reason why you want to create the WMS as a feature layer? This is probably the error. You can add the WMS as a normal layer. Here is the customized code which works for me and adds the WMS to the map:
var serverConnection = new CIMInternetServerConnection { URL = "https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wms_topplus_open?request=GetCapabilities"/*src.MapUrl*/, Anonymous = true, HideUserProperty = true };
var connection = new CIMWMSServiceConnection { ServerConnection = serverConnection, Version = "1.3.0"/*src.Version*/, LayerName = src.Title };

Layer featLayer = null;
await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
{
    featLayer = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer(connection, MapView.Active.Map);
    // this is what changed. Create a Layer instead of a FeatureLayer
});
if (featLayer != null)
{
    CIMBaseLayer bsl = featLayer.GetDefinition();
    if (bsl is CIMWMSLayer) wmsMapLayer = bsl as CIMWMSLayer;
}


That works fine :) Now I use WMSLayer. The mistake with the FeatureLayer I grabbed from the ESRI Help Site: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/sdk/api-reference/topic11794.html
